# Расширение Chrome с активацией

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Я написал расширение для Google Chrome, и оно работает.

В файле `popup.html` прописаны строки с подключением скриптов `<script></script>`, которые в дальнейшем добавлюят функциона на определенных страницах.
Теперь я хочу сделать так, чтобы воспользоваться функционалом расширения могли только зарегистрированные на моем сайте пользователи. Для этого достаточно сделать ajax запрос на одну страницу и получим ответ о том, есть ли польователь в базе.

Если пользователя нет, то нужно сделать так, чтобы расширение не работало, и при просмотре содержимого `popup.html` , чтобы не было ни ссылок, ни каких-либо намеков на мои скрипты.

Каким образом дать полный доступ зарегистрированным пользователям на моем сайте, и полностью обделить не зарегистрированных?

*Мне нужны только грамотные наставления, а код я и сам напишу.*

Comment: `Вариант 1`. Обфускация кода. Т.е запутать его, сделать малочитаемым. `Вариант 2`. [Native Client](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client). Это песочница для запуска скомпилированного кода C/C++. Т.е переписать расширение на С++ к примеру.

Comment: `Вариант 3`. Перенести часть логики на сервер.

Answer (score 1):

> Мне нужны только грамотные наставления, а код я и сам напишу.

Ну так пишите )) Вы же сами ответили:

> Для этого достаточно сделать ajax запрос на одну страницу и получим ответ о том, есть ли пользователь в базе.

Делаете запрос к сайту, проверяете есть ли пользователь с логином и паролем в БД, если есть, то отвечаете ОК и возвращаете токен для авторизации в дальнейшем. Если нет в БД, то отвечаете НЕ ОК и подсказку выводите, мол регистрируйтесь и все такое.

Comment: Пользователь может легко изменить это место в коде. А если отдавать скрипт, то гугл не пропустит расширение в магазин. Так что что-то сомнительная рекомендация.